# Input field is not working in IE11. How can I troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

In my Angular application, I have a simple input field that is nested inside a dropdown menu. In Firefox, it works normally, I can enter text when I click inside the input field.

The only the problem is that in IE11 it does not work. When I say it does not work, I mean that the input field can't be clicked, thus I can't enter anything into the text area.

Here is the code that I have utilized:

**main.html**

```
<span class="dropdown hidden-xs">
    <i class="tcm-chevron glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down expand-icon dropdown-toggle"
       aria-hidden="true"
       role="button"
       aria-labledby="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"
       ng-src="{{dropdown_appExperience}}"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       alt="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"></i>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu appExperience tileContextMenu">
        <li class="gridster-form"
            role="form"
            aria-labeledby="Gridster Layout Form"
            alt="Tile Display Input column Input Row">

            <span class="dropdown-text">
                Col <input type="text" value="tiledata.col" ng-model="tiledata.col" class="input-col">
                Row <input type="text" value="tiledata.row" ng-model="tiledata.row" class="input-row">     
                <i class= "fa fa-arrows"></i>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Here is my CSS stylesheet in case this could become useful:

**style.css**

```
.tileContextMenu:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -15px;
    left: 135px;
}

.tcm-chevron {
    color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.input-col {
   text-align: center;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
}

.input-row {
   text-align: center;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
}

.gridster-form {
   color: #000;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix the input field? I have isolated this code in a JSFiddle -- and it works just fine.

My question to you, is how should I troubleshoot this problem? I don't know what should be the next course of action... Any suggestions would help.

I apologize for any ambiguity (confidentiality reasons limit what I can share)

Comment: Check whether if any other HTML element like div overlapping your input element.

Comment: thanks, there is nothing overlapping the dropdown menu